# Обмен данными между WCF сервисами

Tags: c#, wcf

Добрый день.

Помогите разобраться.

Нужно создать `WCF` сервис, который будет взаимодействовать с другим `WCF` сервисом.
Для начала нужно реализовать метод, который передает данные (логин и пароль) по указанному адресу и получает в ответ идентификатор пользователя.

Не могу понять как именно реализовать интерфейс и метод который будет обращаться по определенному адресу к определенному методу (`Login()` ), передавать ему логин, пароль и забирать ответ в виде поля идентификатора.

Спасибо.

Решение нашел:
[Простой пример использования WCF в Visual Studio 2010](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116764/)

Comment: Не понятно в чем трудность. Guid Login(string login, string password) или речь идет о WCF безопасности

Comment: есть интерфейм
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [WebGet]
        [OperationContract]
        string Login(string login, string password);
    }
и класс
class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string Login(string login, string password)
        {
            
        }
    }

как именно нужно указывать куда конектиться,к какому методу обращаться и как забрать ответный параметр?

адрес нужного сервиса задавать в App.config или так
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://someIp/Webservice.retail/retail.asmx")]
public interface IService1 {}

?

Comment: Рассматривайте данный WCF сервис как WCF клиента. Задайте настройки клиента в конфиге ну и дальше как с клиентом.